# Nest.js + Prisma: I can't create record with relations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, nestjs, prisma

I'm pretty much stuck with that issue for more than a day and tried my best to sort it out but feeling no luck. I want to connect category and subCategory fields to product table before creating a product using Prisma + PostgreSQL so that each product will be in relation with those existing models. Looked up nearly all the tutorials on youtube and even articles on medium but they just tell you how to create product without making any connection to foreigner tables like subcategory or category.I have the following models defined:

## **schema.prisma**

```
model Product {
  id            String      @id @default(uuid())
  name          String
  description   String
  price         Float
  media         Media[]
  category      Category    @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId    String      @unique
  subCategory   SubCategory @relation(fields: [subCategoryId], references: [id])
  subCategoryId String      @unique
  createdAt     DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime    @updatedAt
  reviews       Review[]
  cartItem      CartItem?   @relation(fields: [cartItemId], references: [id])
  cartItemId    String? @unique
  variants      Variant[]
  tags          Tag[]
  orderItem     OrderItem?
  slug          String? @unique
  stock         Int
  
 
  @@index([categoryId])
  @@index([subCategoryId])
  @@index([wishlistId])
  @@index([cartItemId])
  @@index([slug])

}

model SubCategory {
  id         String    @id @default(uuid())
  name       String
  slug       String @unique
  description String?
  products   Product[]
  createdAt  DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime  @updatedAt
  category   Category  @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  categoryId String

  @@index([categoryId])
}

model Category {
  id            String        @id @default(uuid())
  name          String
  slug          String @unique
  description   String?
  subCategories SubCategory[]
  createdAt     DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime      @updatedAt
  products      Product[]

  @@index([id])
  @@index([name])
}
```

## **product.service.ts**

here i casted built-in Prisma`ProductUncheckedCreateInput` type because categoryId and subCategoryId fields only exist in this type and ProductCreateInput doesnt have these fields unfortunately.

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  constructor(
    private databaseService: DatabaseService,
    private redisService: RedisService,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
  ) {}

  async createProduct(
    createProductDto: Prisma.ProductUncheckedCreateInput,
  ): Promise<Product> {
    const category = await this.categoryService.findCategoryById(
      createProductDto.categoryId,
    );

    if (!category) {
      throw new Error('Category not found');
    }

    const newProduct = await this.databaseService.product.create({
      data: {
        ...createProductDto,
        slug: await this.generateSlug(createProductDto.name),
        category: { connect: { id: createProductDto.categoryId } },
        subCategory: { connect: { id: createProductDto.subCategoryId } },
      } as Prisma.ProductUncheckedCreateInput
    });

    await this.redisService.saveProductToCache(newProduct.id, newProduct);
    return newProduct;
  }

  async generateSlug(name: string): Promise<string> {
    const slug = name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
    return slug;
  }
}
```

## **request body for test**

```
{
    "name" : "test product 1",
    "description" : "test product desc 1",
    "price" : 1574,
    "stock" : 12,
    "categoryId" : "32d9ade1-3a9f-4940-ba4b-d0cbb72cdd78", //existing categoryId
    "subCategoryId": "1761d675-f6f5-4921-9302-c1dacb0226ed" // existing subCategoryId

}
```

## **error message returning 500**

```
ERROR (17060): 
Invalid `this.databaseService.product.create()` invocation in

  1446 if (!category) {
  1447     throw new Error('Category not found');
  1448 }
ÔåÆ 1449 const newProduct = await this.databaseService.product.create({
         data: {
           name: "teest ├╝r├╝n 43",
           description: "tesqwet desc bu 22232",
           price: 1574,
           stock: 12,
           categoryId: "32d9ade1-3a9f-4940-ba4b-d0cbb72cdd78",
           ~~~~~~~~~~
           subCategoryId: "1761d675-f6f5-4921-9302-c1dacb0226ed",
           slug: "teest-├╝r├╝n-43",
           category: {
             connect: {
               id: "32d9ade1-3a9f-4940-ba4b-d0cbb72cdd78"
             }
           },
           subCategory: {
             connect: {
               id: "1761d675-f6f5-4921-9302-c1dacb0226ed"
             }
           },
       ?   id?: String,
       ?   createdAt?: DateTime,
       ?   updatedAt?: DateTime,
       ?   isFeatured?: Boolean,
       ?   isBestSeller?: Boolean,
       ?   isPublished?: Boolean,
       ?   isDiscounted?: Boolean,
       ?   discountAmount?: Float | Null,
       ?   media?: MediaCreateNestedManyWithoutProductInput,
       ?   reviews?: ReviewCreateNestedManyWithoutProductInput,
       ?   cartItem?: CartItemCreateNestedOneWithoutProductInput,
       ?   wishlist?: WishlistCreateNestedOneWithoutProductsInput,
       ?   variants?: VariantCreateNestedManyWithoutProductInput,
       ?   tags?: TagCreateNestedManyWithoutProductsInput,
       ?   orderItem?: OrderItemCreateNestedOneWithoutProductInput
         }
       })

Unknown argument `categoryId`. Did you mean `category`? Available options are marked with ?
```

Here are what i have tried so far:
I created my custom DTO implementing the relavant prisma schema to cast the corresponding types properly.
Also,set the category, subCategory, categoryId and subCategoryId fields as optional in prisma schema to see if that will change the result.
I even tried to remove the type `Prisma.ProductUncheckedCreateInput` inside create method of prisma which i casted to `data` property, but none of them worked, maybe im just missing something critically important detail, if you guys point out where im exactly mistaken i will more than happy, feeling a bit stuck after trying many things but ending up with nothing.. endless thanks in advance